# Perform Maven Release with dry-run checkbox from jenkins

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

Need to Trigger "Perform Maven Release" of other job by using command smthing like this

```
curl 'https://192.10.160.105/jenkins/view/job/mavwn/m2release/' 
    -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
    --data 'releaseVersion=$releaseVersion&developmentVersion=$developmentVersion&json={ releaseVersion: $releaseVersion, developmentVersion: $developmentVersion}&Submit=Schedule+Maven+Release+Build'
```

mentioned in

"https://medium.com/@fercalderon/how-to-trigger-a-maven-release-job-from-a-pipeline-job-in-jenkins-6449cf2e6263"

But in the maven Jenkins job there is dry-run checkbox to select, How to select dry-box through given command and schedule a build? Please share if any one has any idea?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this to select a checkbox when triggering the build

`&name=dry-box&value=on`

```
curl 'https://192.10.160.105/jenkins/view/job/mavwn/m2release/' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--data 'releaseVersion=$releaseVersion&developmentVersion=$developmentVersion&name=dry-box&value=on&json={ releaseVersion: $releaseVersion, developmentVersion: $developmentVersion}&Submit=Schedule+Maven+Release+Build'
```